# Using Android play billing v3 to query list of available subscriptions?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

In my app, I can query the available list of managed item on Play Developer Console, but the subscription list is not, I can't get any subscription's skuDetails at all.
Here's my code:

```
try {
    mMoreItemSkus = new ArrayList<>();
    mMoreItemSkus.add("excalibticket_12");
    mMoreItemSkus.add("excalibticket_30");
    mMoreItemSkus.add("excalibticket_60");
    mMoreItemSkus.add("excalibticket_monthly ");

    mMoreSubSkus = new ArrayList<>();
    mMoreSubSkus.add("excalibticket_monthly ");
    mMoreSubSkus.add("excalibticket_60");
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, mMoreItemSkus, mMoreSubSkus, mGotSkuListListener);
} catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
    complain("Error querying inventory. Another async operation in progress.");
}
```

Inside mGotSkuListListener:

```
SkuDetails sd = inventory.getSkuDetails(sku);
RkLogger.d(TAG, "debugging..." + sku + ": details is " + sd);
```

The output is for example:

```
debugging...excalib_ticket_monthly: inventory doesn't have details
```

So, is subscription query not supported currently?
Thanks!

Comment: P/S: Oh, my wrong, I put wrong subscription id, a space character at the end.